# Is it possible to simultaneously remove and get a copy of an object from C++ std::vector or std::deque?

Tags: c++, c++11, deque

In Java, the `Deque` class has [removal methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#removeFirst%28%29) for the ends that actually return the element returned.
In C++, it seems like the only way to achieve the same behavior is to first explicitly copy the element and then pop it.

```
std::deque<int> myDeque;
myDeque.push_back(5);

int element = myDeque.back();
myDeque.pop_back();
```

Is there a mechanism to do both simultaneously?

Comment: Removing `[java]` as the answer won't be about Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write your own wrapper function template:

```
// Precondition: !container.empty()
// Exception safety: If there is an exception during the construction of val,
//                   the container is not changed.
//                   If there is an exception during the return of the value,
//                   the value is lost.
template <typename C>
auto back_popper(C & container) -> decltype(container.back())
{
    auto val(std::move(container.back()));
    container.pop_back();
    return val;
}
```

Usage:

```
auto element = back_popper(myDeque);
```

You cannot get around the fundamental problem that motivates the separation of `back()` and `pop_back()` in the first place, which is that the element's copy or move constructor may throw exceptions and that you may lose the popped element when this happens. You could mitigate it on a case-by-case basis by returning a non-throwing object, e.g. a `unique_ptr`, which would trade off risk of losing the element for a dynamic allocation, but obviously that's a personal choice you have to make which the standard doesn't make for you.

For example:

```
// Guarantees that you either get the last element or that the container
// is not changed.
//
template <typename C>
auto expensive_but_lossless_popper(C & container)
-> typename std::unique_ptr<decltype(container.back())>
{
    using T = decltype(container.back());

    std::unique_ptr<T> p(new T(std::move(container.back())));
    container.pop_back();
    return p;                // noexcept-guaranteed
}
```

**Edit:** I added `std::move` around the `back()` calls, as @Simple suggested. This is legitimate since the moved-from element is no longer needed, and many real-world classes come with noexcept move constructors so that this covers a large number of cases, and the "lossless" workaround only offers an advantage for a small number of "weird" types which have no noexcept moves.

Comment: The name `back_popper` sounds more like a class than a function IMO.

Comment: After I posted my answer I saw your edit and you explain it with code and a comment, so: +1

Comment: @DanielFrey: I went further and explained an alternative solution :-S

Comment: That just shows why it is important to not have a "standard" way of doing this: There is no one-size-fits-all solution and you need to decide for yourself how to handle the problem. For example for the OP using `int`, there is no risk as `int` never throws when copied.

Comment: You really want to put the value returned from `new T` into the `unique_ptr` immediately to make sure that it can never be leaked, as `pop_back()` does not offer the nothrow-guarantee (AFAIK).

Comment: As long as decltype(container.back()) has a non-throwing move constructor (which I think a lot of types do), the original code should offer the guarantee that you either get the last element or the container is not changed

Comment: @JohnBandela: I tried to subsume all that by saying "case-by-case basis" :-)

Answer (score 10):

By design, C++ does not offer such a mechanism out of the box to ensure **exception safety**:

When you try to implement it, you first make a copy of the element, then pop the container and finally you want to return the object to the caller. But what happens when the copy constructor for the last operation throws an exception? The object is no longer in the container and you, as a caller, did not received a copy of it. To prevent that and to offer the strong exception guarantee on the container's operations, an operation that returns the element that is simultaneously popped is not supperted directly.

Comment: In C++11, don't we have a way to identify objects that promise to not throw at copy construction? Then, the library could provide a copy-pop-and-return method for such element types.

Comment: @Walter In theory that would be possible, you could even change the return type from `void` to `T` for `pop_back` based of `std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value`. Or you could go one step further and use move operations and `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value`. But as you can see, the number of things to consider (is the type copyable and/or movable?) is not trivial and AFAIK no one wrote a paper to suggest it yet.

Comment: @Walter Your suggestion is discussed in more detail from a thread-safety point of view in section 3.2.3 of Anthony Williams's [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to loose the exception safety, you can restrict this method using SFINAE:

```
// 
// Precondition: !container.empty()
//               
template <typename C>
auto back_popper(C & container)
-> typename std::enable_if<std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<
                             decltype(container.back())>::value,
                           decltype(container.back())>::type
{
    auto val = std::move(container.back());
    container.pop_back();
    return val;
}
```

or `static_assert` (work that out for yourself). (*note: edited to avoid any copies in case there is a move constructor, follow Simple's comment.*)

Comment: This should probably be `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` instead.

Comment: @Simple Yes, but it may not be movable and still be nothrow copyable ... allowed for all eventualities (I think), see edit.

Comment: If the type isn't movable then `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` will check if it is nothrow copy constructible instead due to how it is defined. Note that the `return std::move(val)` prevents copy elision. You should just write `return val`.

Comment: Also, you will actually need to do a copy as well on the first line. So you need to check for both.

Comment: Or just `std::move(container.back())`.

Comment: @Simple: Excellent point, I took the liberty of stealing that!